# How can i implement a login for a specific drupal site on another drupal site?

Tags: drupal, authentication

I have two **independent** drupal-installations on the same server (one is the public area the other one is the private area). I want the (already registered) users to login to the private site from the public site. This shall be just a redirection, but before the authentication, because the user credentials are handled on the private installation. I imagine this as a kind of a tunnel.

I am using Drupal 6.22.

Comment: It's not 'gibberish', but a bit more information is needed ;)
Can you describe the setup and intended login procedure a bit more precise? (E.g. do the installations share a common top level domain, on which instance are the user 'already registered', how should the login be presented, etc.)

Comment: ok, i'll try to clarify: two independent drupal installations (6.22 = "public" and 6.19 ="private") on the same server. "public" is the main-domain and the "private" is a subdomain of it. The "private" area holds a lot of internal information and is used as a communictaion platform via a ticket-system. The users are registered on this installation. For the public area no login (exept the admin) is needed. Before the "public" installation was established, the "private" instance was also used for the public stuff.

Comment: And because the "private" area is very complicated and "handmade" the goal is to keep these areas separated until the "private" area is migrated. In future this will be handled with a multisite installation.

Comment: The login should be presented like the ordinary drupal-login, but sould reflect the new design. Probably the easiest way would be just to link to the "private" login...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the public site, and the private site are two sub-domain of the same domain, then you can use [Bakery Single Sign-On System](http://drupal.org/project/bakery).

You can see it in action on the drupal.org sub-domains. When you need to log in to groups.drupal.org, you are really logging in to drupal.org.

> Bakery provides a "single sign on" feature for Drupal based sites that are on the same second-level domain (i.e. example.com, subsite.example.com, subsite2.example.com). It could also provide support for any other website that implements the same web cookie, xmlrpc, and POST methods.